# Why is ActiveRecord leaving off the last element when parsing a string as data for an array attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Postgres. I have an ActiveRecord model with an integer array column, like so:

```
t.integer "foo", array: true
```

If I assign a ruby array to it, it works as expected:

```
> @instance.foo = [6,7,8,9,1]
> @instance.foo
=> [6, 7, 8, 9, 1]
```

However, if I assign a string representation of this array, it seems to try to parse the data, but for some reason it always leaves off the last element.

```
> @instance.foo = "[6,7,8,9,1]"
> @instance.foo
=> [6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Which version of Rails is this? My quick'n'dirty testing with Rails4.2 give me `@instance.foo` being `[]`.

Comment: the version is rails 5

Comment: I'm honestly curious why you expect `@instance.foo = "[6,7,8,9,1]"` to do anything sensible. I'd expect an exception but it seems that the `pg` gem blindly stumbles into confusion instead. If you trace through the code all the way into the [pg gem](https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg/blob/master/ext/pg_text_decoder.c#L176) where the actual parsing takes place, you'll see that it is looking for strings in the usual PostgreSQL array-as-string format (`'{6,7,8,9,1}'`).

Comment: Hmm, seems that Rails is commingling MVC layers by trying to get the model to do the controller's job and badly botching it. The text decoder that it is using isn't meant for processing user input, it is meant for processing database output.

Comment: @muistooshort I agree, I was surprised it was attempting to handle that at all.

Comment: A couple more cases: `@instance.foo = "{6,7,8,9,1}"; @instance.foo #=> [6, 7, 8, 9, 1]`, `@instance.foo = "6,7,8,9,1"; @instance.foo #=> [nil, 7, 8, 9]`